# Is it Correct to always say $xA = A^{T}x$?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

Is it always correct to say $xA = A^{T}x$, where $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times  n}$. Is there any special proof beyond just assuming some matrices and vectors and multiplying them??

Comment: You cant multiply matrices of that form in general.

Comment: Think about what the dimensions of the objects involved are. You can only multiply an $a\times b$ by a $c\times d$ (in that order) if $b=c$.

Answer (score 3):

When you multiply matrices, you cannot say $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ because that doesn't say if you represent that by a column or a row matrix. You must either say
$x \in\mathbb{R}^{1\times n}$  (row) or $x \in\mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}$ (column).

Now, if $A \in\mathbb{R}^{m \times  n}$ the only valid multiplication (in general) is

$$y = A x $$
with $x \in\mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}$ and $y \in\mathbb{R}^{m\times 1}$

That, because you can multiply two matrices of sizes ${r \times s}$ and ${t \times u}$  only if $s=t$ (and the result has size $r \times u$)

Further, transposing the equation above, we can also write

$$y^T = x^T A^T $$

So, you equation is not true, in general. It's only true for a $1 \times 1$ matrix.